# Wrong SSL certificate being served for App Engine custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

We have an App Engine app that hosts an internal HR/intranet system. Some, but not all, of our users are reporting that they get a security warning (see he image below). It looks like the wrong SSL certificate is being served. I install a wildcard cert for our domain in the Google Apps cpanel, but it looks like Google's certificate is being served instead. How do I go about troubleshooting this?

[image: security warning]

Answer (score 0):

If some but not all users get this warning you might check what is so special about the users which get the warning. Do they use a specific (old?) browser, are they behind some kind of firewall or similar things? It might be that SNI (server name indication) is an issue, but it is really hard to say from the existing information. It is not even clear what the existing certificate should be so that one cannot compare if the host serves both, one with SNI and one without.

Apart from that it I would consider it a bad idea to host an internal HR/intranet system on the public internet.

Comment: I have to find out which version of Firefox it is exactly, but from the screenshot I can tell it's a recent one. This user's chrome browser is up to date though. And they're not behind a firewall (this happens at home and in the store). But it is pretty apparent (to me) that **the app engine service is serving the wrong certificate**. I'd like to troubleshoot why that's happening. As for having an "intranet" on the public internet — you need to authenticate to get into this system. It's not like anyone on the internet can view our content. Plenty of companies do this.